# Flutter animated SliverAppBar with Animated Positioned Image

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, flutter-sliverappbar

I am trying to replicate this animation with my `appBar`:

[image]

I know I can use `SliverAppBar` and simply animate the `textSize`. But how would I implement the logic for the image? It moves to the right and slightly shrinks.

This is what I have for the `text`:

```
  SliverAppBar(
    expandedHeight: 200,
    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
      title: Text('Test', textScaleFactor: 1),
    ),
    pinned: true,
  ),
```

Any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: try [SliverPersitentHeader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html)

Comment: @pskink I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470499/custom-sliver-app-bar-in-flutter-with-an-image-and-2-text-widgets-going-into-app) answer on SO, but the animation is a bit different. I would like my widgets to animate to their place and size. Not that another widget simply appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You play with `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`

```dart
class AppSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final t = shrinkOffset / maxExtent;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0, .7), //perhaps it should also use lerp
          child: Text(
            "Title",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: ui.lerpDouble(34, 14, t)),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment:
              Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topCenter, Alignment.topRight, t)!,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.settings),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 200;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And used on

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: AppSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                height: 12222,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is `lerp` doing?

Comment: [lerp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/lerp.html) is beautiful method choosing value in-between two based on `t`=>  `lerp(a, b, t) = a + (b — a) * t`. I've `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AnimatedPositioned class which flutter already provide .
Check this link

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html

You can use it and the change the position and size depending on a specific action .