# Make collapsible profile screen which pins profile picture to appbar

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement the following screen transition and I am facing challenges on how to go about it.

[image: expanded state] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget you need to use is `SliverAppBar`. You can checkout these references:

- Flutter's Introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSc7qFzxHDw
- SliverAppBar class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html
- FlexibleSpaceBar class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html
- Custom SliverAppBar: [Custom Sliver App Bar in flutter with an Image and 2 Text widgets going into app bar on scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470499)